# VBA Dynamic userform gives "Object variable or With block variable not set" error

Tags: vba, excel

Bellow is my attempt to dynamically create a frame, add a (dynamically created)label to it, then add said frame to another frame in my userform.

But in the with part it gives Error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set"

What I am doing wrong? Really struggling to do more advanced vba logic while maintaining a clean modern/efficient code.

```
Dim newf As MSForms.Frame

'First the description
With newf.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    'Formating it
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectEtched
    .Caption = ComboBox1.Value
    .Height = 20
    .Width = ComboBox1.Width - 10
    .Left = 10
    newp.Font.Size = 12
End With
'FrameProduct already pre exists
Me.FrameProducts.Controls.Add newf
```

Comment: you have declared that newf is an msforms.frame, but you did not actually create one using the `set newf = ...` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just setting the variable, not creating the object, it seems that the only way to create a control I need to call .controls.Add method, so the solution ended up being these slick nested withs

```
Dim newf As MSForms.Frame
Set newf = Me.FProducts.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
With newf
    .Visible = False
    'First the description
    With .Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectEtched
        .Caption = ComboBox1.Value
        .Height = 20
        .Width = ComboBox1.Width - 10
        .Left = 10
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    .Visible = True
End with
```